# Local Storage in Excel Add-in

Tags: office-js

Are there any security concerns with using HTML5 Local Storage in an Excel Add-in?  Is there any way for the user to clear their local storage within the Excel Add-in similar to how you would for a native browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in UI to do this within an Add-in. But you could create your own UI and code to delete any Local Storage that was created in the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no security issue if you use localstorage with encrypted data and clear after get used. Basically its iternally uses IE browser to run excel add inns.